# How can I link a set of toggle buttons like radio buttons?

Tags: python, button, gtk, radio-button, toggle

I am using Python 3 with gobject introspection for Gtk. How can I have more than one toggle button linked together so they behave similar to tabs or radiobuttons - e.g. one is selected by default, and when another is `clicked` the previously `active` one is de-selected.

I have tried using `set_sensetive`, but that greys out the widget that it is applied on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set_active()` (or `props.active`). Alternatively, you can create some `Gtk.RadioButton` widgets and set `draw_indicator` property to `False`. In the latter case you can create radio groups in normal way, without custom handling.

Comment: Your "alternative" solution seems to me the preferred one.

Comment: @doublep, See my reply to iain's answer for your first suggestion, but I will accept your answer for the 'alternative' suggestion.

Comment: @doublep, BTW I think you mean `Gtk.ToolButton.set_mode(False)`

Comment: His solution works for me. Just make sure you check that the widget is active in the togglebutton's callback, otherwise it will execute whether being set to false or true.

Answer (score 6):

Use a Gtk.RadioButton and set draw indocator mode to False

```
button1 = Gtk.RadioButton("Product Codes")
button1.set_mode(False)
```

https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/ToggleButton.html#Gtk.ToggleButton.set_mode

[image]

Thx to:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15123955/1907997
  and
- [How can I link a set of toggle buttons like radio buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120746/how-can-i-link-a-set-of-toggle-buttons-like-radio-buttons#comment21314495_15123955)

Answer (score 1):

You listen to the toggle signals on the toggle button then call `set_active()` on the other ones. You need to block the toggled signals while calling `set_active()`so that you don't get into a loop.

Comment: I've created a callback function that is executed when the `clicked` signal is emitted, which sets the button active again if it was active before it was clicked (because I don't want all of the buttons to be not active), but it appears that the function is executed before the callback is executed...