# GTK # Toggle Button Grouping

Tags: c#, .net, mono, gtk, gtk#

I want to group some TooggleButtons in GTK# so that when one button is Active all the other buttons remains inactive.Is there a way do it by grouping rather than writing the code to deactivate all other buttons in the clicked event of each button?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [Here's an example](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=C%3aGtk.RadioButton.RadioButton(Gtk.RadioButton%2cstring)) in the documentation:

```
RadioButton button1;
RadioButton button2;
button1 = new RadioButton("Button 1");
button2 = new RadioButton(button1, "Button 2 - in Button 1's group");
```

Comment: It's not radio button it's toggle button.Does this apply to toggle button too

Comment: No. A radio button is, by definition, a toggle button that does what you describe. A toggle button is a toggle button that doesn't.

Comment: My question is with respect to ToggleButton.Can i use similar approach for a Toggle Button?

Comment: No. You will have to subclass ToggleButton and build that behavior yourself, at which point you will have recreated RadioButton. If you're trying to get a RadioButton that _looks_ like a ToggleButton, then you could do that, but perhaps you should reconsider - always consider what the expectation of your users is with respect to existing UI idioms.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to ask for a gtk radio button to look like a toggle button, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54404995/516188

set `mode` to `false`, or set the `draw-indicator` property to `false`.